# Autolayout Constraint with multiple Labels

Tags: ios, autolayout

I read a lot about autolayout & constraints but I still have many problems.
I designed my current view based on 4.7 inch layout.
I want this design to be automaticaly adapted to 4 inch and above.

I fixed the UIView (red rectangle) with the right constraints.
The Label 1 is set up with 3 constraints (top, center, width, height) with a priority of 1000
I tried to chain constraint "less or equal" or "greater or equal" to all others elements with priority of 750 except the last image which have fix constraint.

But all my constraints are red and the result is not as wanted.

Where I misunderstood ?

[image]

Comment: The screenshot cannot tell about your story. Can you provide a screen shot from storyboard including your constraints ? and also there has to be some kind of red arrow near your view controller segment, follow that arrow to see your mistakes

Comment: I updated the picture. I have some errors with Inequality Constraint Ambiguity on Label2 top and bottom constraint

Comment: @Jojo Red Lines indicates two things - One there are more than one constraint for that label axis and second there is no constraint for that axis. Try by removing and reassigning constraints

Comment: The problem of the red lines came from the "less or equal" / "greater or equal constraint". If I set up all constraints to "equal" I dont' have any problem

Comment: Then maybe you should set them all as "equal" and add an aspect ratio constraint for your objects to resize themselves

Comment: Can you please upload an image what layout you want to achieve?